# Laravel 5 @section not working when loading JS in child template

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have a base layout which contains following:

```
@section('javascripts')
    <script src="<?php echo asset('js/all.js') ?>"></script>
@endsection
```

In my child template I have following:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

<!-- some other html code -->
@section('javascripts')
    @parent
    <!-- some local scripts -->
    <script>
        $(function() { console.log('test'); });
    </script>
@endsection
```

My javascripts from both parent and child are not loading at all.

However, following works:
Base layout:

```
<!-- load main scripts -->
<script src="<?php echo asset('js/all.js') ?>"></script>
@yield('javascripts')
```

Child template:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

<!-- some other html code -->
@section('javascripts')
    <!-- some local scripts -->
    <script>
        $(function() { console.log('test'); });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that you can use `stacks` but for your question, you are not closing the `section` correctly. Instead of `@endsection` you have to use `@show` at your base layout.

```
@section('javascripts')
    <script src="<?php echo asset('js/all.js') ?>"></script>
@show
```

Answer (score 0):

You can better use the @stack and @push structures here I think. This would look like this

In your parent template you can add a @stack tag where you would like to see your javascript code like this

```
<head>
    <title>My website</title>
    @stack('scripts')
</head>
```

Then in your child template you will use the @push tag it will look like this.

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
     $(function() { console.log('test'); });
</script>
@endpush
```

This will push your javascript from the child template to the stack of the parent template in.

I found a topic on laracasts where it is explained.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/blade-push-and-stack-are-they-here-to-stay